# Many-to-many Propel relationships with attribute

Tags: many-to-many, propel

I'm trying to setup a schema consisting of the following (only the relevant parts are displayed):

```xml
<table name="song" phpName="Song">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="title" type="varchar" size="255" required="true"/>
</table>
<table name="artist" phpName="Artist">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="name" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
    <column name="surname" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
    <column name="information" type="varchar" size="255"/>
</table>
<table name="song_artist" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="song_id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="artist_id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="song">
      <reference local="song_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="artist">
      <reference local="artist_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

The above is functioning correctly, but I also want to add an attribute to the cross-reference table so that I can filter the results by a category.

Each song can have many artists (composers, lyricists and singers). Also, an artist can have many songs, but can have composed many songs (as a composer), can have written lyrics for many songs (as a lyricist) and can have sung many songs (as a singer).

By querying:

```php
$song->getArtists()
```

I retrieve all the artists of the song, but without any information about who are the `composers/lyricists/singers`.

I tried adding an extra field in the schema for `song_artist` so I can filter the results by:

```php
$song->getArtists()->filterByCategory('composer')
```

The table schema was the following:

```xml
<table name="song_artist" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="song_id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="artist_id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="category" type="enum" valueSet="composer, lyricist, singer" required="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="song">
      <reference local="song_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="artist">
      <reference local="artist_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

Propel breaks down when I use this, and it also breaks down when I try adding it as a third Primary Key (as a category_id with foreign key towards a "category" table).

From what I reckon, Propel does not accept any other field for the cross-reference tables to work on a many-to-many relationship. Is there a workaround for this problem or do I have to setup three different tables for composers, lyricists and singers (along with all the other necessary adjustments)?

Answer (score 2):

With the last schema you gave, you should be able to filter the results by category using a little "trick" like this one:

```php
$criteria = ArtistQuery::create()
  ->useSongArtistQuery()
    ->filterByCategory('composer')
  ->endUse();
$song->getArtists($criteria)
```